# Resolve several macros in a same line with std::regex_search

Tags: c++, stl

I want to resolve macros in a same line. 
So I define macros in a map:

```
map<string, string> collection;
collection["ComputerName"] = "Train-Alpha";
collection["State"] = "Unloaded";
```

The macros notation is $(MacroName) so the input line looks like:

```
string line = "Running on $(ComputerName) while $(State)";
```

And I use this regular expression:

```
regex expression("\\$\\(([^}]+)\\)");
```

But my code below consider the 'largest' sub pattern rather than the smallest:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <map>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    string line = "Running on $(StationName) while $(State)";
    map<string, string> collection;
    collection["Station"] = "Train-Alpha";
    collection["State"] = "unloaded";
    regex pattern("\\($\\([^}]+\\))");
    smatch match;

    while (regex_search(line, match, pattern))
    {
        auto variableName = match[1].str();
        auto it = collection.find(variableName);
        if (it != end(collection))
        {
            auto keyword = "$(" + variableName + ")";
            auto value = it->second;
            boost::replace_all(line, keyword, value);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << line << endl;
}
```

Comment: If macro names may be nested, a regular expression is insufficient:  `"this line $(has-a-$(nested-macro))"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors in your code:

1. The first mapped value should be changed:

   ```
   collection["Station"] = "Train-Alpha";
   ```

   by

   ```
   collection["StationName"] = "Train-Alpha";
   ```
2. The regex should also be changed:

   ```
   regex pattern("\\($\\([^}]+\\))");
   ```

   by

   ```
   regex pattern("\\$\\(([^)]+)\\)");
   ```

   Or you can also use a [Raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) to avoid escaping the backslashes (or any character):

   ```
   regex pattern(R"(\$\(([^)]+)\))");
   ```

---

[See a slightly modified working version on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/yn7dKw)